# linux + Informix cant startup + external EMC storage 

Tags: linux, database, informix

I have Linux machine with Informix DB
from the Informix log I see the following
please advice what could be the problem ( my Informix cant startup )

```
 13:40:45  Warning: ONCONFIG dump directory (DUMPDIR) '/tmp' has insecure permissions
 13:40:45  Event alarms enabled.  ALARMPROG = '/usr/informix/etc/alarmprogram.sh'
 13:40:45  Booting Language <c> from module <>
 13:40:45  Loading Module <CNULL>
 13:40:45  Booting Language <builtin> from module <>
 13:40:45  Loading Module <BUILTINNULL>
 13:40:50  listener-thread: err = -25572: oserr = 99: errstr = : Network driver cannot      bind a name to the port.
 System error = 99.
 13:40:50  sql_listener: ASF_LISTEN failed

 13:40:50  Attempting to bring listener thread down.

 13:40:50  Server stopped.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Warning: ONCONFIG dump directory (DUMPDIR) '/tmp' has insecure permissions
```

This means /tmp has 777 as a permission bits. You could ignore this , just make sure sticky bit is set for /tmp.

```
 13:40:50  listener-thread: err = -25572: oserr = 99: errstr = : Network driver cannot      bind a name to the port.
```

As for this one, please check if the port in question(informix DB port) is already used or not via this command

```
netstat -tulpn
```

It will show the port occupied with details showing pid and program name if root ran it.

These are general debugging steps as per the error log